# I uploaded my Laravel 8 project to Cpanel while i got an error

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 and i uploaded my project to cPanel. In my local server it works fine but in live server it show me error:

**syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'** on

**return $this->belongsTo(JournalHead::class, foreignKey: 'journal_head_id');**

Below is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JournalEditorial extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'journal_head_id',
        'editorial_title',
        'editorial_author',
        'abstract',
        'editorial_page_no',
        'editorial_pdf_file',
        'editorial_doi_link',
    ];

    public function getEditorialHead() {
        return $this->belongsTo(JournalHead::class, foreignKey: 'journal_head_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: `foreignKey: 'journal_head_id'` is no valid PHP syntax. I think you need to give an associative array as the second argument https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are positional arguments, where the 2nd is foreign key, the 3rd is  local key:

```
return $this->belongsTo(JournalHead::class, 'journal_head_id');
```

Here's the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

Answer (score 0):

no need to type foreign key before journal_head_id..
try like this:

```
public function getEditorialHead() {
        return $this->belongsTo(JournalHead::class,  'journal_head_id');
    }
```